# Advantages of Multiple Fault contract types in WCF Services

Tags: wcf

Can someone please help me with the advantages of having multiple Fault contract types in single application with different componenets exposed as WCF services.

Any help on this will be highly appriciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Fault contracts help to define what types of errors to expect from a particular service.  On the client side, this allows the application to catch and manage conditions depending on the type of fault.

For example (taken from [here](http://developergeeks.com/article/104/introduction-to-wcf-fault-contracts)), you could have service with several types of fault contracts:

```
[ServiceContract]  
interface ICalculator  
{  
   [OperationContract]  
   [FaultContract(typeof(InvalidOperationException))]  
   [FaultContract(typeof(string))]  
   double Add(double number1,double number2);  

   [OperationContract]  
   [FaultContract(typeof(DivideByZeroException))]  
   double Divide(double number1,double number2);  
   //More methods  
}
```

And on the client side, you would have this:

```
CalculatorClient proxy = new CalculatorClient( );  
try  
{  
   proxy.Divide(2,0);  
   proxy.Close( );  
}  

catch(FaultException<DivideByZeroException> exception)  
{...}  

catch(CommunicationException exception)  
{...}
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Garrett, Thank you. But I need to know more in general what advantages you can have by having multiple fault contracts when compare to having only one.

Comment: I thought that's what I described.  Multiple contracts allows the client to determine different actions based on the type of fault. It also can give more information with the fault.